# What is the orbit of a set?

Tags: group-theory

I have the following question:

Let $ G = S_4 $. What is $\textrm{Orb}(H)$ (under $G$) when $H  =V_4$, $H = \textrm{Sym} \{1,2,3\}, H = <(1234)>$ ($G$ is acting by conjugation)?

I don't quite get this - surely the orbit of a set is just the same set?

Comment: How is $G$ acting?  By left multiplication?  By conjugation?

Comment: @SpamIAm Sorry, G is acting by conjugation

Comment: The orbit of $H$ under conjugation by $G$ is indeed at LEAST $H$ (take conjugation with the identity of $G$). But it may be bigger. Try playing with a few small examples to see how this happens. It is a special case when $\mathrm{Orb}(H) = H$. In this case, $H$ is said to be a $\mathbf{normal~subgroup}$ of $G$.

Comment: In general, You have $|G:N_G(H)|$ different elements in orbits of $H$ under conjugation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...surely the orbit of a set is just the same set?"  Nope!  Consider this: $\text{Orb}(H) = H$ iff $\sigma H \sigma^{-1} = H$ for all $\sigma \in S_4$ iff $H \trianglelefteq S_4$.  In general, a subgroup can have (many!) distinct conjugates.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you!